# Picasso not loading image in activity

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

I am trying to use the Picasso library in a new Android project but I'm running into a problem that does not cause my program to crash but nevertheless doesn't display the image.

Here is my code:

```
Picasso.with(StartGameActivity.this)
    .load(imageUrl)
    .resize(imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight())
    .centerInside()
    .into(imageView);
```

And here's the corresponding XML layout code:

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:background="@drawable/round_image"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

I've tried several times tweaking the params to the `Picasso.with` method but had no success. Can you please help me figure this out?

**UPDATE** I attached some logging to the code to facilitate debugging.

This is the full snipped of the code that is supposed to load the image:

```
if (imageUrl != null) {
    Logger.d(MainApplication.TAG, "Dimensions are " + imageView.getWidth() + "x" + imageView.getHeight());
    Logger.d(MainApplication.TAG, "Fetched image url is " + imageUrl);
    Picasso.with(StartGameActivity.this)
        .load(imageUrl)
        .fit()
        .centerInside()
        .into(imageView);

    Logger.d(MainApplication.TAG, "Finished loading image into view.");
}
```

Here's what it returned:

```
Dimensions are 632x400
D/GreatApp : Fetched image url is  http://i.imgur.com/7j82rtQl.jpg
W/Settings﹕ Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
D/GreatApp : Finished loading image into view.
```

Thanks in advance, folks.

Comment: check ur url, is it correct

Comment: Check adb logs.. You should see the errors there

Comment: Check your Manifest whether it have required permissions,Check the url in a web browser whether it loads the image

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: the url is correct: http://i.imgur.com/BibbYdcl.jpg

Comment: I think a bit more context would be good - are there any other View in your layout that could overlay the ImageView? In which lifecycle method are you loading the image? Are you certain that you call `imageView.getWidth()` and `imageView.getHeight()` at a point when the imageView is already measured (it might have a width/height of 0 before that). Have you tried replacing the `resize` line with `fit()`?

Comment: hello @david.mihola, I tried `fit()` but it didn't work. The image view is not being overlaid by another view, I know that because it has a different background color and is clearly not affected when the activity loads.

Comment: Interesting... try adding a `Listener` to your Picasso instance and see what that writes to your logs...